# how do you make a sidebar filter to go along the content when you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site where it has a sidebar filter on the left. I want to make the filter scroll as well as I scroll the content, such that I can access it all the time (therefore I don't have to scroll to the top all the time to access the filter). How do I do so? Here's my [website](http://dev.shopious.com/directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at position: fixed css property, this will help you out
the fixed property will keep a div or some other element on a "fixed" place on the screen

more info on this website: http://learnlayout.com/position.html